# Check multiple columns in multiple sheets and output specific values

Tags: excel, vba

Find data in vba Excel in two plans

I would like to take a value that is in sheet1 column a and find it in column f of sheet2 and check the data in column z and ad and in sheet3 column f and check the value in column j .

If you find both, place neutral, or if not, place plan2 if you find a value in the z or ad column.

If you find value in j of sheet3. put plan 3 on plan1 line of code sought in column k what is happening in my code is that it puts only plan1 or neutral..

It seems that it doesn't look for plan3.. I don't know what else to do..

```
    Sub MacroOne()
        Dim wsPlan1 As Worksheet
        Dim wsPlan2 As Worksheet
        Dim wsPlan3 As Worksheet
        Dim lastRowPlan1 As Long
        Dim lastRowPlan2 As Long
        Dim lastRowPlan3 As Long
        Dim Value As Variant
        Dim row As Long
        Dim col As Long
        Dim data1s As String
        Dim data3 As String
    
        Set wsPlan1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Plan1")
        Set wsPlan2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Plan2")
        Set wsPlan3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Plan3")
        
        wsPlan2.Range("F:F").NumberFormat = "000000000"
        wsPlan3.Range("F:F").NumberFormat = "000000000"
        
        lastRowPlan1 = wsPlan1.Cells(wsPlan1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
        
        For row = 4 To lastRowPlan1
            Numb = wsPlan1.Cells(row, "A").Value
            lastRowPlan2 = wsPlan2.Cells(wsPlan2.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).row
            
            For col = 4 To lastRowPlan2
                Value = wsPlan2.Cells(col, "F").Value
                Value2 = wsPlan2.Cells(col, "Z").Value
                Value3 = wsPlan2.Cells(col, "AD").Value
                If MCI = Value And Value2 > 1000 Or Value3 > 1000 Then
                    data1s = "data2s"
                    Value2 = ""
                    Value3 = ""
                    Exit For
                Else
                    data1s = ""
                    Value2 = ""
                    Value3 = ""
                End If
            Next col
    
            lastRowPlan3 = wsPlan3.Cells(wsPlan3.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).row
            
            For col = 3 To lastRowPlan3
                ValueJ = wsPlan3.Cells(col, "J").Value
                Valuef = wsPlan3.Cells(col, "F").Value
                If Valuef = MCI Then
                    If ValueJ >= 1000 And wsPlan3.Cells(col, "J").Value <= 149999 Then
                        data3 = "data3"
                        ValueJ = ""
                        Valuef = ""
                        Exit For
                    ElseIf ValueJ > 150000 Then
                        data3 = "data3150k"
                        ValueJ = ""
                        Valuef = ""
                        Exit For
                    Else
                        data3 = ""
                        ValueJ = ""
                        Valuef = ""
                    End If
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next col
    
            wsPlan1.Cells(row, "K").Value = IIf(Data1 <> "" And data3 <> "", "Not Find", IIf(Data1 <> "", Data1, IIf(data3 <> "", data3, "")))
    
            data3 = ""
        Next row
    End Sub
```

Comment: Can someone help me.. I don't have much knowledge in vba to solve this..

Comment: you have to be more specific with your explanation on what you are trying to do